# Ultra Miniature Coaxial connector what does 50ohm stand for

Tags: antenna, cables, coaxial

In my current project I designed a PCB board for the ESP8266EX chip. Instead of making an onboard antenna, like in the [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf) described, I have placed [this](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/_Hirose_U-FL-R-SMT-1-80_Hirose-HRS-U-FL-R-SMT-1-80_C88374.html)
connecter. The goal is to be able to choose a bigger antenna with higher dBi.

Since the board will be placed inside an enclosure, I need to somehow connect the antenna with the connector via cable. The datasheet describes the antenna pin for 50 ohm impedance (when using the pi matching circuit). The connector on the lcsc page somehow says 50 ohm also. Does this mean, if I add a 50 ohm antenna, I'll have 100 ohm impedance on the pin that is meant to have 50 ohm on? Or does the 50 ohm impedance on the connector stand for the ability to connect a 50 ohm impedance antenna to it?

Thus further I'm not quiet sure how to search for the coaxial cable... nor the antenna. Big websites like amazon don't seem to have anything when searching for "Ultra Miniature Coaxial (cable)". Is there a special website for these type of applications?

Comment: Amazon is a source for consumer articles, not electronics components.  You **can** buy components there, but the site is not set up to help you find things by specification - and the sellers are often not specialists, either, so they are no help.  Digikey, Mouser, RS Components, Arrow, and others are set up to help you find specific parts and to provide proper datasheets for the parts.

Comment: " the 50 ohm impedance on the connector stand for the ability to connect a 50 ohm impedance antenna to it?" would be the correct interperation. Check out the term "impedance matching" and why it is importan. For these miniature coaxial cables, I recommend that you get ready made cable assembly from e.g., https://farnell.com instead of making your own.

Comment: Impedance in signal cables and connectors (=wave impedance) happens to have the same dimension (=Ohm) as the resistance or AC circuit impedance. But the impedance in cables and connectors describe the proportion how much the propagating radiowave in the cable or connector contain electric field vs magnetic field. The propagation of the wave without reflection needs continuous wave impedance or a load which has the same resistance as the wave impedance. The wave is the field between the wires, but one can measure the induced current in wires and the caused voltage between the wires. Study!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 50 ohm connector is designed to be connected with 50 ohm cable, and 50 ohm track on the board. It's a description of the *geometry and material* of the dielectric used in the cable, connector and track. This controls their impedance, or the ratio of voltage to current of a signal that flows through them.

You get best results when they are all the same impedance, so that a 50ohm signal launched into the track can continue with the same V/I ratio through the connector and into the cable.

Small errors in impedance are usually negligible. Large errors can cause loss of signal, and so communication problems.

Comment: Isn't it a function of both geometry and material? The dielectric used in the coax affects its impedance, right?

Comment: @Hearth Yes, I was using 'geometry' generously, to include the stuff that was in the gap, but perhaps I need to be explicit.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir!